# Copy one of the 2 duplicates from 2 different sheets into the 3rd one

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have 1 spreadsheet with multiple sheets.
The 1st and the 2nd sheets **sometimes** have similar data in the rows (duplicates). Also, each sheet has a column (8) with a checkbox.

[image]

**Task:** I need to move one of the duplicates to the 3rd sheet when the checkboxes in both sheets (1st and 2nd) are checked.

Here is the code that moves the row when it's checked in a single sheet.

Can someone help me modify it to complete my task?

```
function onEdit(e) {
let range = e.range;
let col = range.getColumn();
let row = range.getRow();
let val = range.getValue();
let source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());


if (sourceSheet.getName() == 'SHEET1' && col == 8 && val == true){

  let data = sourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,7).getValues();
  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET2');
  targetSheet.appendRow(data[0]);
  sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
}

if (sourceSheet.getName() == 'SHEET2' && col == 8 && val == true){

  let data = sourceSheet.getRange(row,1,1,7).getValues();
  let targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('SHEET3');
  targetSheet.appendRow(data[0]);
  sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
}
}
```

[Sample Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bGYgYZ6lb7iFXZmZ_tvLH_bZilNh0NbxhLkb74Q7yKg/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand `Task: I need to move one of the duplicates to the 3rd sheet when the checkboxes in both sheets (1st and 2nd) are checked.`. Can I ask you about the detail of the current issue of your script and your goal?

Comment: I have 2 sheets, that contain the same data in rows. I need to copy this data from any of these two sheets to the third one. It should happen when both rows have the same criteria in column H, which is the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Apply filter()

You can add the `filter()` method (combined with the `JSON.stringify()` method) to your script to determine if a row is a duplicate of another from the other sheet. The modified script should somehow look like this:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var range = e.range;
  var col = range.getColumn();
  var row = range.getRow();
  var val = range.getValue();
  var source = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName(source.getName());
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet3');

  //If Sheet1 checkbox is triggered
  if (sourceSheet.getName() == 'Sheet1' && col == 8 && val == true) {
    var rowArr = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
    var lastRow2 = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getLastRow();
    var sheet2Values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(1, 1, lastRow2, 8).getValues();
    var count = sheet2Values.filter(x => {
      return (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(rowArr[0]))
    });
    var otherRow = sheet2Values.map((x, i) => {
      if (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(rowArr[0])) {
        return i;
      }
    });
    if (count.length > 0) {
      var otherRow = sheet2Values.map((x, i) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(rowArr[0])) {
          return i;
        }
      }).filter(y => y);
      rowArr[0].pop();
      targetSheet.appendRow(rowArr[0]);
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
      var otherSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
      otherSheet.deleteRow(otherRow[0] + 1)
    }
  }

  //If Sheet2 checkbox is triggered
  if (sourceSheet.getName() == 'Sheet2' && col == 8 && val == true) {
    var rowArr = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2').getRange(row, 1, 1, 8).getValues();
    var lastRow = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastRow();
    var sheet1Values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1, 1, lastRow, 8).getValues();
    var count = sheet1Values.filter(x => {
      return (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(rowArr[0]))
    });
    if (count.length > 0) {
      var otherRow = sheet1Values.map((x, i) => {
        if (JSON.stringify(x) === JSON.stringify(rowArr[0])) {
          return i;
        }
      }).filter(y => y);
      rowArr[0].pop();
      targetSheet.appendRow(rowArr[0]);
      sourceSheet.deleteRow(row);
      var otherSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
      otherSheet.deleteRow(otherRow[0] + 1)
    }
  }
}
```

### Output

Based on your sample spreadsheet, the modified script should work as shown below:

[image]

Please take note that the appendRow() method appends any row to the last non-empty row in the sheet. A row with a checkbox is not considered to be an empty row thus explains the behavior of the output.

### Reference

- [filter()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_filter.asp)
- [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp)

Comment: Feel free to ask if you have any questions with regards to the answer.

Comment: Hello, PatrickdC
Thank you for helping me. I really appreciate it

I see your sample, that is what I need. But the row from Sheet2 also should be deleted.
Also I tried to run your script in my spreadsheet, but it didn't work.
I've made a separate spreadsheet to share with you. Maybe you know how to fix it

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bGYgYZ6lb7iFXZmZ_tvLH_bZilNh0NbxhLkb74Q7yKg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: By the looks of it, the script did not work because sheet 1 and sheet 2 have different numbers of columns, I'll adjust the script acordingly

Comment: I have modified the script. Kindly check if it fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you for editing the code. But unfortunately, it didn't work.
Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: Can you please elaborate what happened on your side? What errors have you encountered on your side? As of now, I can only think of two issues at hand. 1. Have you tried modifying the sheet names accordingly? 2. Have you given authorization to the script to run in your spreadsheet?

Comment: Anyway, I noticed that you placed the new script in 2.gs in your sample spreadsheet. I commented out everything on the other .gs file and ran the onEdit() function in 2.gs (ignoring the error) just to trigger the authorization process. It worked fine on my side.

Comment: Now it's working. Thank you a lot!
Maybe it was the earlier onEdit code that was the problem.

Can you also help me to delete both duplicates after one of them was copied to SHEET3?

Comment: What do you mean? It already deletes data from both sheet 1 and sheet 2 when data is already copied in data 3.

Comment: I've done a few tests and in some cases, it just doesn't delete the data from sheet1 or sheet2. It happens quite often
I've tried to move this code to my original spreadsheet to check, but any changes make the script not work (

Comment: Can you share the scenarios wherein the script fails so that I may recreate the issues on my side?

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by scenarios. But when I check duplicates, the script copies and pastes the row in sheet3 from the last sheet I pressed the checkbox, but the first one still has data with checked checkbox. Doesn't matter what are the sheets' order to check the checkbox
Here is the video I recorded https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KjozZ7NLcK_BKkW1neQMy6UlsRYu8CVQ/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have updated the script. I have changed the `+3` in `otherSheet.deleteRow(otherRow[0] + 3)` to `+1` to avoid the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Would that do what you want ?

```js
function copyDuplicateRows() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheet1 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var sheet2 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet3 = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Sheet3"); // destination sheet
  
  var data1 = sheet1.getDataRange().getValues();
  var data2 = sheet2.getDataRange().getValues();
  
  // Use a JavaScript object to keep track of duplicate rows
  var seen = {};
  
  // Iterate through data1 and copy unique rows to sheet3
  for (var i = 0; i < data1.length; i++) {
    var row = data1[i];
    var key = row.join(); // create a unique key for each row
    if (!seen[key]) {
      seen[key] = true;
      sheet3.appendRow(row);
    }
  }
  
  // Iterate through data2 and copy unique rows to sheet3
  for (var i = 0; i < data2.length; i++) {
    var row = data2[i];
    var key = row.join();
    if (!seen[key]) {
      seen[key] = true;
      sheet3.appendRow(row);
    }
  }
}
```